# Pandas qcut returning out and bins does not appear consistent on the left boundary

Tags: pandas

If you do simply this:

```
out, bins = pd.qcut(range(10), 4, retbins=True)
```

out is:

```
[(-0.001, 2.25], (-0.001, 2.25], (-0.001, 2.25], (2.25, 4.5], (2.25, 4.5], (4.5, 6.75], (4.5, 6.75], (6.75, 9.0], (6.75, 9.0], (6.75, 9.0]]
Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(-0.001, 2.25] < (2.25, 4.5] < (4.5, 6.75] < (6.75, 9.0]]
```

bins is:

```
array([0.  , 2.25, 4.5 , 6.75, 9.  ])
```

Note that all bounds from 'out' and 'bins' are consistent except the '0' (left boundary). It seemed to be -0.001 in the category interval but 0.0 in the bins array.

This causes a problem for me since I serialized bins as is, and re-apply it back on new data. The context is machine learning, where you apply the exact same binning and categorize/embedding during inference on new data. Because of the difference in the left boundaries, the resulting categories don't match up and I have a bug.

Anyone knows why the categorical interval is -0.001 but 0.0 in the 'bins' while all other intervals seemed ok.

Comment: Apparently, one needs to control the precision. There's a precision param for qcut, but i have not been able to use this to achieve my desired goal.

Comment: Since `qcut` uses left-open intervals, the left endpoint of the first bin is extended so it includes the smallest element in the data.

Comment: @root. Thanks. I realized after staring at that asymmetric looking ( and ]. I got a workaround/solution after playing around.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a rounding to me .

Your code with a slight mod :

```
 pd.qcut(np.arange(0.1,1,0.01), 4, retbins=True)
```

Here are the results :

```
([(0.099, 0.322], (0.099, 0.322], (0.099, 0.322], (0.099, 0.322], (0.099, 0.322], ..., (0.767, 0.99], (0.767, 0.99], (0.767, 0.99], (0.767, 0.99], (0.767, 0.99]]
 Length: 90
 Categories (4, interval[float64]): [(0.099, 0.322] < (0.322, 0.545] < (0.545, 0.767] < (0.767, 0.99]]
```

Bins are

```
 array([0.1   , 0.3225, 0.545 , 0.7675, 0.99  ]))
```

Note that the `0.099` of the left boundary has been rounded off to `0.1`

Answer (score 0):

I did the following, it feels like a hack. This works for me for now.

As @root pointed out, the -0.001 is there because the qcut uses left open interval. I.e. (0, 1] is anything bigger than 0 and equal or less than one but exclude 0 itself, while (-0.001, 1] will include 0. We can control the precision by doing this:

```
out, bins = pd.qcut(range(10), 4, precision=4, retbins=True)
```

which gives (-0.0001, 2.25] as first interval. I found this precision spec is important just in case its magnitude is small if you leave it (default). It can get 'lost' in type conversion downstream and will cause problem. I.e. you don't want it ever to be -1e-7 (which can happen depending on your data).

Then you fix bins[0] to have that -0.001:

```
bins[0] = out.categories[0].left
```

Such that now, if you perform this:

```
 pd.cut(range(10), bins)
```

it will generate categorical values that match the original qcut using only the bins. This solves my problem. It feels like a hack. Would love to hear a more robust solution though.